# SMplayer can't play playlists like ASX 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04, mplayer, smplayer, playlists

It can't play asx files, like the the ones created by MythTVs found in mythTV. This was working fine in 14.04. After debugging this it seems to be smplayer is not passing the **-playlist** parameter to mplayer.

But in smplayers log it was meant to be doing this from 2012
(2012-01-12)  0.6.11 pre 3

Also passing the stream url to mplayer with the -playlist worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here

http://forum.smplayer.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8363

It needs a newer version (v16) which has the option to pass playlist feature to mplayer in Preferences.

You can get the latest version of smplayer by using the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Comment: Don't forget you can accept your own answer, so others can see this  was correct.